# Resolving Javascript errors likely related to Gantry framework

Tags: javascript, errors, framework

I'm trying to resolve some Javascript errors on [a site I'm working on](http://www.associatedkyotoprogram.dreamhosters.com/) (built using the Gantry framework), as I have a sneaking suspicion they're keeping some plugins from working properly. For instance, the menu does not properly expand on small screens when the "menu" button is clicked, and [support docs for the plugin](http://support.sevenspark.com/symptom/ubermenu-symptoms/cant-expand-responsive-menu-toggle/) suggest that's caused by Javascript errors. Moreover, I'd just like to clean things up so that I'm avoiding errors in general.

Examining the console log, I see the following messages:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Class is not defined rokmediaqueries.js:80
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'addEvent' www.associatedkyotoprogram.dreamhosters.com/:95

I'm nearly certain the ReferenceError has something to do with Gantry, because the "rok" prefix is used by RocketTheme, the team behind Gantry. I'm less sure about the TypeError.

Either way, I don't have the knowledge to resolve these issues. Could anyone please point me in the right direction (or explain to me how to fix them)?

Thank you so very much.

Comment: These are javascript errors related to a commercial theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.

Thanks to some feedback on reddit (see [this](http://redd.it/1lcraf) thread and [this](http://redd.it/1lctxh) one), I learned that the issue was that the mootools.js script was being loaded far too late.

I solved it (rather inelegantly, I'm sure) by adding this line to themes/rt_gantry_wp/index.php, around line 30 or so (before the `if` blocks):

```
$gantry->addScript('/wp-content/plugins/gantry/js/mootools.js');
```

It's no longer throwing either of those errors. The menu still doesn't work, but that's, apparently, a different problem.

The code's a rat's nest, but this solved the issue, and will hopefully point anyone who has this problem in the future toward a more elegant solution.